# Базовые принципы дизайна для backend-программиста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, дизайн, веб-дизайн

Здравствуйте, я сам дизайном не занимаюсь, но иногда нужно сверстать какую-то страничку, может не с оригинальным или сверх-крутым дизайном, но что-то, что бы не сильно было стыдно показать кому-то или немного использовать в качестве прототипа.

Так что может вы знаете какие-нибудь принципы, ссылки, ресурсы, книги, которые расскажут, как не дизайнеру сделать не уродливый дизайн? 
Что бы можно было сделать что-то не плохое, что бы передать основную мысль и что бы оттуда не выпирали куски шаблонного кода Bootstrap`a.

Дело в том, что почти все, что я находил было про то, как что-то сделать, но почти ничего не пишут когда это стоит делать.
Например куча статей, как сделать красную кнопку на css, но никто не пишет, где и когда красная кнопка будет выглядеть красиво.

Пока что я нашел где-то упоминание, что из пропорцию стоит попробовать не только 50:50 и 1:2, но и золотое сечение и последовательность Фибоначчи:
http://pixelgene.ru/articles/golden-ratio.html

И две интересные статейки про некоторые общие принципы:
http://habrahabr.ru/company/iloveip/blog/261857/
http://habrahabr.ru/company/iloveip/blog/263061/

Так что можете порекомендовать какие-то общие принципы, которые в большинстве случаев помогут сделать что-то более-менее неплохое?

PS: Заранее извиняюсь за такой обобщенный и не технический вопрос, но это на самом деле важно и самому на эту тему нагуглить почти ничего не удалось...

**UPD** В принципе по User Experience и проектировке интерфейсов некие основные принципы есть, например [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/247367/) или [это](http://infostart.ru/public/63902/). Но вот про дизайн самой "картинки", хорошо ли оно будет выглядеть толком ничего, глухо.

Comment: "Дизайн для недизайнеров" от Робина Уильямса, начните с этого.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Красота - это субъективное понятие, а вы пытаетесь загнать ее в строгие математические рамки. Ну и не путайте дизайн и User eXperience.

У вас должно быть чувство прекрасного, хороший вкус. Это можно тренировать.
Смотрите, что делают другие, оценивайте, сравнивайте. Знакомьтесь с лучшими произведениями искусства. Наслаждайтесь видами природы.

Запоминайте дизайны, которые вам нравятся. Не бойтесь заимствовать чужие идеи (хорошие художники копируют, великие художники воруют).

А вообще лучше не лезьте в то, что вам не близко, юзайте готовые шаблоны.

Comment: Да, красота - субъективна, да, чувство прекрасного. Только вот это чувство прекрасного выполняет работу не генерации "хорошего", а распознавания "хорошо/плохо". Но все же есть некоторые эвристики, которые **неплохо** смотрятся в **большинстве** случаев, про них и вопрос.

Comment: И UX с дизайном не путаю, просто упомянул, что для UX некоторые принципы, законы и эвристики постоянно на слуху.